# Comparing models by R2 and RMSE

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, correlation, cross-validation

I posted this question on stack.exchange but was recommended to move here.
I am developing model predictions using pls and h2o packages which lead to 2 models: pls.model and h2o.model. The R-square (square of pearson correlation) and RMSE for each round of cross-validation are shown below: 
R2:

```
i     R2.PLS     R2.H2O
1   1 0.4415108 0.6232292
2   2 0.3754088 0.6056992
3   3 0.4267580 0.6204750
4   4 0.3505282 0.6062691
5   5 0.2870766 0.5344183
6   6 0.3858786 0.5794828
7   7 0.3449946 0.5692314
8   8 0.2974582 0.5522208
9   9 0.3446449 0.5694339
10 10 0.3987684 0.5561757
```

RMSE:

```
i  rmse.pls rmse.h2o
1   1  8.839967 40.99896
2   2  9.347349 29.94260
3   3  4.240366 14.75890
4   4 17.901563 29.89181
5   5  4.686803 66.04993
6   6 31.717909 10.28799
7   7  2.066342 32.74828
8   8 15.979214 21.05928
9   9 19.454079 10.88551
10 10 27.039400 68.27017
```

I am unable to explain why pls.model has lower R2 but lower error while h2o.model has higher R2 but high error. I checked the scatter plot but no non-linear pattern appear. Would you have any thought of this? And in this case, what should be the better model?

Thanks Phuong